# Rectifier design calculation

Tags: capacitor, filter, ac-dc, bridge-rectifier

I am working on a rectifier design.  For that I am analyzing the formula for capacitor selection.  I came across a [video reference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyRHwtVmDhM&list=PLiFKKHbfBVngrJU2kzZCh6Q-PewjPS_I1&index=5)

[image]

- Io: average output current
- Vo: Average output voltage
- Vc: capacitor voltage
- Im: peak current
- α:duration of peak current
- π: half cycle duration
- Vr: ripple voltage
- Vm1,Vm2:capacitor peak voltage

I understood that for capacitor selection the formula is:

c=(π-α)/π * Io/2fVr

I don't understood how Vm2=Vm1 * Cosα.

Comment: Simply follow the cosine curve in that picture, left from the peak Vm1, for angle alpha. It's right there in the picture.

Comment: thanks for help @Brian Drummond

Comment: You can also have a look at a [paper](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Papers/bulk%20capacitor%20calculations.pdf) I published on the bulk capacitor selection for ac-dc converters.

Comment: @ VerbalKint i will refer this paper for calculations thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple trigonometry:

\$V_{m1}\$ is the voltage at \$t = \pi/2\$. and \$V_{m2}\$ is the voltage at \$t = \pi/2 - \alpha\$.

\$\sin (\pi/2-\alpha) = \cos\alpha\$

Comment: thanks for help @RohatKılıç

Comment: You can accept my answer so that the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 0):

If alpha is 90 degrees, then the stored voltage has decayed down to zero volts.

This is consistent with VM2 = VM1 * cos(90).

Comment: thanks for help@analogsystemsrf